# Как перенести переменную в скобки в кавычках?

Tags: python

```
x = int(input("Type a number of action:"))
if x == 0:
    first = input("Input name:")
    second = input("Input number:")
    book = Addresses(first, second)
    book.adding()
```

Мне нужно передать переменную first и second в скобки класса Adresses в кавычках.. Пробовал разные методы но ничего не работает..

```
class Addresses():
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name=name
        self.number=number
    def adding(self, name, number):
        adressbook = adressbook.data
        book = { name : number }
        f = open(adressbook, 'w')
        f.write(book)
        pickle.dump(adressbook, f)
        f.close
x = int(input("Type a number of action:"))
if x == 0:
    first = input("Input name:")
    first = '"' + first + '"'
    second = input("Input number:")
    second = '"' + second + '"'
    book = Addresses(first, second)
    book.adding()
```

Comment: А правильная проверка if x == 0: вы попадёте туда только, когда number of action равно 0 ?

Comment: @splash58, вполне может быть - это, возможно, что-то типа списка бездельников. Не было ни одной акции им сделано, то нужно знать имя и номер, чтобы выяснить его адрес. А вот что first и second кавычки теряют, вот это удивительно.

Comment: @Сергей , В строке book = Adresses(first, second)
first и second это текст который мы получили с input, он должен быть подан в скобки в кавычках иначе метод просто не срабатывает.. Очевидно если я напишу Adresses("first","second") то метод возьмет эти два слова, а мне нужно что бы он взял туда то, что напишет пользователь.

Comment: Забавно, что я даже не сразу сообразил, как написать надо (ответ ниже), так что + 1 за вопрос:-)

Comment: Фраза "Пробовал разные методы но ничего не работает" обычно означает, что ничего не пробовал. Потому что когда пробуют разные методы, то делятся своими результатами и говорят, почему не устраивает результат. А тут еще и непонятно, что за "передать в кавычках". Советую для начала разобраться, что делает Adresses(first, second), а то судя по комментарию никакие кавычки там не нужны.

Comment: @Эникейщик, судя по комментариям выше и под ответом, пробовал Хуан действительно многое, я потому всё же и ответил. У него проблема ХY, скорее всего. И, представляете, мне кто-то за совершенно верный ответ на поставленный (неверный?) вопрос минус поставил:-) А ведь ответ очень неплох для базы знаний SO, как ответ на вопрос.

Comment: У вас совершенно бессмысленный класс. Врядли аргументом при создании должна быть конкретная запись, Скорее,  то, что вы называете переменной adressbook - то есть данные файла. Сейчас откуда вы берете место хранения совершенно неясно. Никакие кавычки  вам не нужны. Да и добавление новой записи полностью уничтожает остальные

Comment: Ну вот, как и было сразу понятно - никакие дополнительные кавычки тут не нужны! Если у вас что-то не работает, то сначала нужно разобраться что именно и почему. А уже потом думать как решить, а не сначала придумывать какое-то решение, а потом смотреть, исчезла ли проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На вопросы в комментах полный ответ не увидел, так что понадеюсь, что вариант ниже подойдёт, и вы его не пробовали.

Вам просто надо провести сложение строк, а кавычки подать, как символ. То есть - вставить одни кавычки в другие кавычки:-)

```
x = int(input("Type a number of action:"))
if x == 0:
    first = input("Input name:")
    first = = '"' + first + '"'
    second = input("Input number:")
    second = '"' + second + '"'
    book = Adresses(first, second)
    book.adding()
```

Comment: TypeError: Addresses.adding() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'number'

Comment: Я пробовал подобное

Comment: Прости что не отвечал на эти вопросы.. не особо вижу в этом смысла. Мне нужен ответ неважно сложный он или простой, главное - правильный. Возможно этот ответ есть правильным но я где-то натупил...

Comment: Я поэтому и просил привести ваши варианты и спрашивал про ваш класс. Так как проблема не в кавычках, предположительно - если вы сделаете `print (first)`, то вы увидите, что переменные в кавычках теперь.

Comment: дайте минимально воспроизводимый код (с классом, остальное не надо), иначе не понятно, о чём мы говорим. Посмотрите, что такое "проблема ХY" - вы уверены на 100%, что это не она у вас?

Comment: ```
class Addresses():
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name=name
        self.number=number
    def adding(self, name, number):
        adressbook = adressbook.data
        book = { name : number }
        f = open(adressbook, 'w')
        f.write(book)
        pickle.dump(adressbook, f)
        f.close
```

Comment: в вопрос добавьте, пожалуйста. Тут все сбилось же. И теперь я вообще потерялся, за ответ одновременно и "-1" и галка за принятие его, при том, что написано, что он не помогает...

Comment: -1 поставил не я. Я поставил треугольник выше. Он  засчитался, но не отобразился так как я не имею достаточно репутации.Ответ засчитал потому что подумал что ошибка в моем коде

Comment: 1)book = Addresses(f'"{first}"', "'{second}")
2)book = Addresses('"'+first+'"', '"'+second+'"') пробовал такие варианты

Comment: У вас 95% ошибка в коде или понимании ситуации. не знаю код класса вашего, но если, например, передать в фукцию `''first"` c кавычками, как параметр и распечать уже из функции, то мы увидим, что кавычки отлично передались остались. В общем, если вы тут свой воспроизвидимый пример не дадите, который ошибку выдаёт, то вам не помочь.

Comment: Я отредактировал вопрос и добавил нужную часть кода

Comment: так при чем же тут кавычки? У вас в методе `adding` ждут два аргумента, а вы его вызываете без них - `book.adding()`. Надо тогда `book.adding (first, second)` И, возможно, кавычки эти добавленные как раз теперь не нужны. Cмотрите, сколько времени потратили из-за "не особо вижу в этом смысла":-))

Comment: Простите что потратил ваше время.... был уверен что проблема в кавычках.. В следующий раз буду более внимателен

Comment: Дело не во внимательности. Дело в методологии работы с предполагаемой ошибкой. На будущее:  1) Пробема XY - не подменяйте реальную проблему своим описанием; 2) Приводите сразу в вопросе минимально воспроизводимый код; 3) Если уж вас просят что-то еще привести (если только у просящего рейтинг не 1:-), то приводите. Даже у меня с 2000 репутации интуиция уже неплохо работает, а у Великих с десятками тысяч так вообще зашкаливать должна. Заметьте, я в первом же комментарии под вопросом вашим сообщил, что "странно звучит" вопрос. Успехов!